# Default iOS UINavigationBar animation isn't smooth

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation

I'm working on an application and need to hide the UINavigationBar (and toolbar) to provide a fullscreen mode in the in-app browser.

When the app run this code the animation work just fine.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

When I want to exit from the full-screen mode the animation isn't smooth at all.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

During the animation a black rectangle is visible under the navigation bar, I think it is the UIWebView that resize itself (the toolbar animation work just fine.)

Any idea on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` for hiding the navigation bar, try this:

In your view controller's `viewDidLoad` compute different frames for your navigation bar and your view:

```
// The normal navigation bar frame, i.e. fully visible
normalNavBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

// The frame of the hidden navigation bar (moved up by its height)
hiddenNavBarFrame = normalNavBarFrame;
hiddenNavBarFrame.origin.y -= CGRectGetHeight(normalNavBarFrame);

// The frame of your view as specified in the nib file
normalViewFrame = self.view.frame;

// The frame of your view moved up by the height of the navigation bar
// and increased in height by the same amount
fullViewFrame = normalViewFrame;
fullViewFrame.origin.y -= CGRectGetHeight(normalNavBarFrame);
fullViewFrame.size.height += CGRectGetHeight(normalNavBarFrame);
```

When you want to go fullscreen:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = hiddenNavBarFrame;
                         self.view.frame = fullViewFrame;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];
```

When you want to return to normal:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = normalNavBarFrame;
                         self.view.frame = normalViewFrame;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];
```

Tested this in the iOS 5.1 emulator. Hope you can use that. The "black rectangle" must be the default background color of your window, i.e. a gap between your navigation bar and your view.